# latex for math inline equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

[image]

How can I make inline equation like this?

```
 ${\left\{B,A_1,...,A_m \right\} $
          $\frac{\left\{¬B,C_1,...,C_m \right\}} $} 
           $\left\{A_1,...,A_m,C_1,....C_n \right\} $
```

should I use amsmath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) although it is a good idea to use it anyway (for other functionality it provides). `amsmath` provides `\dotsc` for `...` surrounded by `c`ommas. Otherwise you can just use `\ldots`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For \dotsc

\begin{document}

Some text
$\frac{ \{B, A_1, \dotsc, A_m \} \quad \{\neg B, C_1, \dotsc, C_m \} }{ \{ A_1, \dotsc, A_m, C_1, \dotsc, C_n \} }$
and then some more text.

\end{document}
```

There's also no need to use `\left`...`\right` if you only have regular-sized content within a set.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need any extra packages for this.  Just write the entire expression as a single `\frac`, without leaving or re-entering math mode.

The trickiest part was telling PDFTeX to accept `¬` as a synonym for `\neg`.  If you can use `unicode-math`, this will work out of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{¬}{\neg}

\begin{document}
\( \frac{ \left\{ B,A_1,\dots,A_m \right\} \quad \left\{ ¬B,C_1,\dots,C_m \right\}}
        { \left\{ A_1,\dots,A_m,C_1,\dots,C_n \right\} }
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

Since you appear to be using Times, you could add `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` in PDFTeX or `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` with `unicode-math` to reproduce your screenshot more exactly.  This is with `\usepackage{newtxmath}`:

[image: newtx sample]

Comment: @Sebastiano OK.